# How can I use a project's default build settings in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I have a Visual Studio 2007 project that I successfully upgraded with VS 2010. It says it builds successfully, but while the project's default build settings result in "build successful" message, there are 2 warnings that state:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(990,5): 
warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\MaxSDK-5.1.7\examples\plussz\.\..\..\sdk-build\plussz.dll) 
does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\MaxSDK-5.1.7\sdk-build\plussz.mxe). This      may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(991,5): warning MSB8012: TargetExt(.dll) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (.mxe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
```

and the file never shows up. Furthermore, the file it tries to build has an extension .DLL, but it's supposed to have .mxo.

Anything that allows me to build this thing is a big help, but what I really want to do is output to the project folder (where the source is) as opposed to my user folder. I assume there are some preexisting build settings for this project. Isn't there some way I could use those as opposed to the global variables visual studio uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sounds like the project conversion wasn't all that successful. VS2007? Really?

You should be able to fix this by changing the project properties.

In Visual Studio, right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select `Properties`.
You may want to select `All Configurations` in the Configuration drop down.
Click on `General` in Configuration Properties section.
Set "Output Directory" to: $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\
Set "Intermediate Directory" to: $(Configuration)\
Set "Target Extension" to: .mxo
In the "Linker->General" section:
Set "Output File" to: $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It actually worked correctly, I just didn't see it. Thanks tho.